# Join / Marge of DataFrame with MultiIndex-ed columns having different levels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, outer-join

I have this dummy DataFrame with different MultiIndex levels :

```
A = pandas.DataFrame({"A" : [1, 5], "B" : [3, 5], "Output1" : [6, 8]}).set_index(["A", "B"]).unstack().fillna(0)

  Output1     
B       3    5
A             
1     6.0  0.0
5     0.0  8.0


B = pandas.DataFrame({"A" : [1, 6], "B" : [3, 5], "C" : [33, 55], "Output2" : [6, 7, 8]}).set_index(["A", "B", "C"]).unstack([1, 2]).fillna(0)


  Output2     
B       3    5
C      33   55
A             
1     6.0  0.0
6     0.0  8.0
```

I would like to join both DataFrame-s and get the following result :

```
   (Output2, 3, 33)  (Output2, 5, 55)  (Output1, 3)  (Output1, 5)
A                                                                
1               6.0               0.0           6.0           0.0
5               0.0               0.0           0.0           8.0
6               0.0               8.0           0.0           0.0
```

I was able to get this result using

```
res = B.join(A, how='outer').fillna(0)
```

However when I reverse A and B, B's first level index disappear...and the number of levels seems forced-feed into the first DataFrame of the join assertion.

What is the elegant way to reach the desired result ?

The second problem with the current solution is that it is possible to query the DataFrame A or B as follows :

```
A["Output1"]
B["Output2"]
```

but the result cannot be queried that way as the MultiIndex-s seems to be flattened :

```
res["Output1"] #crash
res["Output2"] #crash
```

Comment: What is exactly your issue? You could do: `res = pd.concat((B, A), axis=1).fillna(0)`

Comment: Yes, it's the same problem : concat((B,A)) provides a different result as concat((A,B)) and the result cannot be queried the same way as A or B : the MultiIndex gets flattened and not possible to call res["Output1"] for instance. I hope it clarifies a bit

Comment: In one index you have 3 levels an in the other two, what would be an appropriate value for for the last level of 'A'?

Comment: Anything would suit, like "-" or "Stop" or None

Answer (score 0):

One approach is:

```
A.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(*t, '-') for t in list(A.columns)])
res = pd.concat((B, A), axis=1).fillna(0)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
  Output2      Output1     
B       3    5       3    5
C      33   55       -    -
A                          
1     6.0  0.0     6.0  0.0
5     0.0  0.0     0.0  8.0
6     0.0  8.0     0.0  0.0
```

Then you can do:

```
print(res['Output1'])
```

**Output**

```
B    3    5
C    -    -
A          
1  6.0  0.0
5  0.0  8.0
6  0.0  0.0
```

If you do not want to modify `A`, you could do:

```
new_A = A.reindex(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(*t, '-') for t in list(A.columns)]))
res = pd.concat((B, new_A), axis=1).fillna(0)
```

Comment: Hello, is it possible to generate the "-"  automatically, to match the col levels of the longest df ?

Comment: also it doesn't work for these two dataframes (especially A)
A = pandas.DataFrame({"A" : [1, 4], "Output1" : [6, 8]}).set_index(["A"]).fillna(0)
B = pandas.DataFrame({"A" : [1, 5], "B" : [3, 5], "Output2" : [6, 8]}).set_index(["A", "B"]).unstack().fillna(0)